The pinned column is not displayed in the ag-grid when using the ngx-scrollbar
What are you trying to do?
I'm trying to use ngx-scrollbar in ag-grid following the provided guide:
What troubleshooting steps have you tried?
I tried changing the externalViewport or externalContentWrapper values, but it didn't resolve the issue.
What are you seeing that does not match your expectations?
The last column (Column 5), pinned to the right, is not displayed.
Steps to reproduce:

Open the provided StackBlitz
Wait until the app is running
Scroll to the right in the table

Environment

Angular: 18.2.13
ngx-scrollbar: 16.1.1
Browser(s): Chrome
Operating System (e.g. Windows, macOS, Ubuntu): Linux

